# SwiftUI: Firebase ForEach list perform edit function unable to edit the selected row item

Tags: firebase, foreach, swiftui

The scenario is currently I retrieved list of data from firebase and store in an array. I used ForEach to loop the array and display by using list. For each row of data in the list, I added a edit button to edit the selected row item. However, when I click on the "Edit" button of a particular row, it always display the data of the first row instead of the selected one.

Here is my first screen:
[image]

The screen when I click on "Edit" button for "Orange Jus":
[image]

**As you can see on my second screen, I clicked for "Orange Jus" but it is showing the "Limau Jus".**

Here is my code for ForEach:

```
struct ManageItemListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var stockViewModel : StockViewModel
    let getLoc: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        self.stockViewModel.getItemDetails(loc: self.getLoc)
        
        return VStack {
            
            List {
                
                ForEach(stockViewModel.itemList) {index in
                    
                    ManageItemView(stockViewModel: self.stockViewModel, itemLst: index, getLoc: self.getLoc)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ManageItemView: View {
    
    let stockViewModel : StockViewModel
    
    let itemLst : ItemList
    
    let getLoc : String

    @State var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

            HStack {
                
                ImageView(vmLoc: self.getLoc, itemId: self.itemLst.id)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    Text(itemLst.name).fontWeight(.semibold).padding(.bottom, 5)
                    
                    Text("RM\(itemLst.price)")
                    
                }.padding()
                
                Spacer()
                
                btnEditItem(stockViewModel: self.stockViewModel, itemLst: self.itemLst, getLoc: self.getLoc)
                
            }.padding(.vertical, 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. For me it fixed it adding the id to the ForEach like this:

```
struct ManageItemListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var stockViewModel : StockViewModel
    let getLoc: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        self.stockViewModel.getItemDetails(loc: self.getLoc)
        
        return VStack {
            
            List {
                
                ForEach(stockViewModel.itemList, id: \.self) {index in //<-- Here
                    
                    ManageItemView(stockViewModel: self.stockViewModel, itemLst: index, getLoc: self.getLoc)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```